# Read a value from offchain storage of a node

Tags: substrate-node-template, storage, rpc, offchain-worker, offchain

I want to read a single value from OffchainStorage of a live substrate node. Is it possible? Assume I can not use `localStorageGet` rpc request because it is an unsafe rpc.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the data stored in the OffchainStorage using offchain worker threads that have read and write access or through the on-chain logic using offchain indexing.

Read more about Offchain Indexing in the [docs](https://docs.substrate.io/learn/offchain-operations/#offchain-indexing).

> Offchain indexing allows the runtime to write directly to the offchain storage without using offchain worker threads. You can enable this functionality to persist data by starting a Substrate node with the --enable-offchain-indexing command-line option.

And take a look at this example [substrate-offchain-worker-demo](https://github.com/jimmychu0807/substrate-offchain-worker-demo/blob/master/docs/indexing.md).

Before start working with Offchain Workers, I'd recommend read this post in the Polkadot Forum [Offchain Workers: Design Assumptions & Vulnerabilities](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/offchain-workers-design-assumptions-vulnerabilities/2548), to understand better possibles vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please see my comment under Xavier's answer. I don't get how to use indexing for reading values. Basically I have a key and I want to read corresponding value through some arbitrary interaction with a node @AlexBean

Answer (score 1):

I think that's impossible.

`offchain-indexing` is an option. The node can access the offchain storage only when it enabled this feature. Not every node enables that.

Also, you might notice that there is also a `localStorageSet` call, anybody can set the storage if you public this call.

Moreover, the node needs to build the offchain DB from the importing logic from block #0. Every node maintains its own offchain DB. The offchain DB can not sync from other nodes.

So, I think that's why it was marked as unsafe.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry but how is `offchain-indexing` an option? I thought its write-only. Let's say target node has offchain indexing enabled, how do I go about reading some offchain value externally from my machine/app/service? using indexing @AurevoirXavier

Comment: I suggest you maintain one and enable the unsafe rpc. Otherwise, I suggest you use subquerry instead of offchain worker. Last year my team switch to subquery from offchain worker. Because there are a lot of issues while interacting with offchain DB.